# I read somewhere JPA makes our application loosely coupled, but I don't understand how it does it? I know that hibernate implements JPA guidelines

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I read somewhere   JPA makes our application loosely coupled.But I don't know understand how it does  it?
I know that hibernate implements JPA guidelines

I read somewhere JPA makes our application loosely coupled.But I don't know understand how it does  it?
I know that hibernate implements JPA guidelines

Comment: Your question will not be better if you repeat sentences

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an orm tool,which maps our entity to relational databases.
There are more tools for mapping java enities to relational databases like top link, toplink .
And jpa is simply a specification to orm tools (hibernate,toplink)
Hibernate follows and implement guidelines set by Jpa.
How it makes application loosely coupled?
Jpa is loosely coupled with Orm tools i.e. orm tools ,it allows to map java entities with tables,by this application doesn't the underlying implenentation and structure of the database.
It is like Jpa acts as a interface and its implementation classes are Orm tools for java.
If you want to switch to one orm tool to other orm tool just change the dependencies and that's all.No need to change code in your codebase.
That's how jpa provides loose coupling in our applicatio.